# While loop ignores print?

Tags: python

Ok so im working on a basic dice game, But when it gets to the while loop it doesnt print the message inside, The message is just a placeholder.

```
    dicenumber = None
    numberchoice = None
    ready = None
    test = "Lol"

    class playerClass():
        points = 0


    class enemyClass():
        point = 0


    def rolldice():
        dicenumber = dicenumber.randint(1,9)

    def start():
        print("Hello welcome to the dice game.")
        print("The goal of the game is to guess what number the dice will land on.")
        print("The option are 1 to 6 and the game is won by getting 3 points.")
        print()
        print("Are you ready to play?")
        print("1 - Yes")
        print("2 - No")
        ready = int(input())



    start()

    while ready == 1:
        print("hello")
```

Comment: why don't you just set, some_var = raw_input("Are you read to play, 1 - yes, 2 - no") then return some_var from your function. Typically don't use a global var.

Answer (score 1):

Use global inside your start function. Also, as you were trying to put while `ready==1`, it will be in infinite loop!

```
dicenumber = None
numberchoice = None
ready = None
test = "Lol"

class playerClass():
        points = 0


class enemyClass():
        point = 0


def rolldice():
        dicenumber = dicenumber.randint(1,9)

def start():
        global ready
        print("Hello welcome to the dice game.")
        print("The goal of the game is to guess what number the dice will land on.")
        print("The option are 1 to 6 and the game is won by getting 3 points.")
        print()
        print("Are you ready to play?")
        print("1 - Yes")
        print("2 - No")
        ready = int(input())



start()

while ready == 1:
        print("hello")
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a scoping issue. `ready` variable defined in a global scope is not updated inside the `start()` function.

Simple demo of what is happening:

```
>>> ready = None
>>> def start():
...     ready = 1
... 
>>> start()
>>> print ready
None
```

Better return `ready` variable from the `start()`:

```
def start():
    print("Hello welcome to the dice game.")
    print("The goal of the game is to guess what number the dice will land on.")
    print("The option are 1 to 6 and the game is won by getting 3 points.")
    print()
    print("Are you ready to play?")
    print("1 - Yes")
    print("2 - No")
    return int(input())

ready = start()
```

You can also make it global as @S.M. Al Mamun suggested, but i would not recommend it. Global variables are needed for sharing data, state between functions. In this case there is no need for it - your `start()` function defines a value for the `ready` variable. It is a single one place where `ready` is defined - no need to make it global. `start()` is an entry point and it would be a good idea to return a "state" (ready variable) from it.

See also:

- [Short Description of the Scoping Rules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291978/short-description-of-python-scoping-rules)

Answer (score 0):

When you access `ready` inside the `start()` method, you are accessing it as a local variable. Python assumes that all variables you use are local, not global. Put `global ready` in the `start()` method before you set the `ready` variable. This will tell python to access `ready` as a global variable.

Answer (score 0):

`ready` is defined in the global scope, but you are setting it in the local scope of the `start` function. Also, your `rolldice` function returns a number from 1 to 9 instead of 1 to 6.

```
from random import randint

class Player:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.points = 0
        self.won = False

    def add_point(self):
        self.points += 1
        self.won = True

print('''
Hello welcome to the dice game.
The goal of the game is to guess what number the dice will land on.
The options are 1 to 6 and the game is won by getting 3 points.

Are you ready to play?
0 - No
1 - Yes'''
ready = int(input())

if ready:
    players = []
    number_of_players = int(input('How many players? '))
    for i in range(number_of_players):
        name = input('What is the name of player {}?'.format(i+1))
        players.append(Player(name))
    winners = []

while ready:
    random_number = randint(1, 6)
    for player in players:
        guess = int(input('What is your guess, {}?'.format(player.name)))
        if guess == random_number:
            player.add_point()
        if player.won:
            winners.append(player.name)
    if winners:
        print('Winners: {}'.format(', '.join(winners)))
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

You are accessing a variable(ready) which was defined originally as a global variable, then you are accessing it in your start function without mentioning in your code('start' function) that is a global variable and finally in your while loop you are again trying to access a variable which you assume it has a value assigned to it.

The other thing is you while loop. when you set ready==1, you need to some where break from your loop if you don't want it to be infinite loop.